# How is a relocation fee of more than 40k taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rent

I'm vacating a rent control apartment in California. The owner of the property is paying me more than 40k in early termination of the rent. How is this money going to be taxed?

Will I end up paying short term capital gains? Or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is ordinary income to you.

You should probably talk to a California licensed CRTP/EA/CPA, but I doubt they'll say anything different. You would probably ask them whether you can treat some of it as a refund of rent paid, but I personally wouldn't feel comfortable with that.

Answer (score 1):

With a $40,000 payment there is a 100% chance that the owner will be claiming this as a business expense on their taxes.

The IRS and the state will definitely know about it, and the risk of interest and penalties if it is not claimed as income make the best course of action to see a tax adviser.

Because taxes will not be taken out by the property owner, the tax payer should also make sure that the estimated $10,000 in federal taxes, if they are in the 25% tax bracket, doesn't trigger other tax issues that could result in penalties, or the need to file quarterly taxes next year.

This kind of extra income could also result in a change or an elimination of a health care subsidy. A unexpected mid-year  change could trigger the need to refund the subsidy received this year via the tax form next April.